# SQL Errors using like and %

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

My script is designed to cycle through environments, hit a database and check to see if any first/last name combination has an associated user ID. I am not sure why I'm getting the error listed below.

```
#/bin/bash

#specify user to search for  *******DO NOT PUT SPACE, ie. jaylefler
echo "Please enter user first name: "
read first_name

echo "Please enter user last name: "
read last_name

echo "Please enter LDAP User ID: "
read ldapuser

echo "Please enter LDAP password: "

stty -echo

read ldappw

stty echo
#logs to write output to
log="ui_${username}_access.log"
finallog="${username}_ui_access.txt"

#create file if not exist, else null it
[[ -f ${log} ]] && cat /dev/null > ${log} || touch ${log}
[[ -f ${finallog} ]] && cat /dev/null > ${finallog} || touch ${log}

#log it all
{

echo "environment"
sshpass -p $ldappw ssh $ldapuser@54.123.777.567 'mysql -h host -u user -    ppassword database -e \
"select user_id from users where first like "%'${first_name}'%" and last like "%'${last_name}'%";"'


} > $log
```

When I execute the script, I receive the following errors:

```
Please enter user first name: 
jay
Please enter user last name: 
lefler
Please enter LDAP User ID: 
jlefler
Please enter LDAP password: 
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%jay% and last like %lefler%' at line 1
jlefler@ubuntu:~/Desktop$
```

Comment: you dont have single quotes around `'jay'` and `'lefler'`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not that familiar with this type of scripting, but it would seem to me that around %jay% and %lefler% there would need to be quotations so that the SQL appears as:

```
select user_id from users where first like '%jay%' and last like '%lefler%';
```

Comment: So what edits need to be made to my scripts? I understand how the SQL statement should be used, but I'm using variables so the syntax won't be the exact same.

Comment: I believe it should look like this: `"select user_id from users where first like "'%${first_name}%'" and last like "'%${last_name}%'";"'` - putting the single quotations outside of the percent signs. I'm not familiar with this type of scripting, though, so that could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem in your code is that the quotation marks are inside of the percent signs. :)

The second problem is that you have created something that is vulnerable to SQL injection.  I have absolutely no idea how to create bound parameters from a Bash script, but you need to figure that out!

Answer (score 0):

The query to MySQL is supposed to output something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name LIKE '%w%';
```

In bash one of the way to concatenate is as follow:

```
mystring="some ${string1} arbitrary ${string2} text"
```

**EDIT:**
So combining all Plus making somethin to expand the strings inside ''. The problem is that shell Can not expand strings between single quotations marks.
Something like this should work:

```
CommandFinale=$($sqlCommand -e "select user_id from users where first like '%${first_name}%' and last like '%${last_name}%';")
```

Then use the variable `CommandFinale` in you connection chain.

I have not bee able to test it but it should be like that or very similar.

Comment: Same error or a bit different? Also Make an `echo` of the string SQL query, make it a variable and echo it, then post it here. Just to see what chain is it creating.

Comment: With the changes you mentioned I get following errors instead: Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.

Comment: remove the query and execute it with only this: `sshpass -p $ldappw ssh $ldapuser@54.123.777.567 'mysql -h host -u user -    ppassword database` see if it works.

Comment: Echoing the query works fine. And the script works without the query. There is something wrong with how it is reading the bash variables.

Comment: That means that is you remove the variables `${first_name}` and put a normal chain it works?

Comment: Doesn't like that either - maybe it is something with quotation? Truly at a loss at this point.

Comment: Check out my answer again, I have edited it. Now it should be closer to what you need.

Comment: Can you explain what I need to put in the sqlCommand variable (syntax) and also how it should look in the code with the rewrite?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70417/discussion-between-user3299633-and-wti).